# Can I Run 2 Entity Framework contexts simultaneously (1 read, 1 read/write)?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am writing a tool that copies data from certain (user selectable) tables in one database to another database running the same schema. Can I use 2  Entity Framework Contexts (each with a different conn string) in the following way or will I run into problems?

1. Read a row from Context1
2. Search for row in Context2 (based on Name for example)
3. If Name Doesnt exist in Context2:

   - make a copy of row from Context1
   - Manipulate some fields in copy
   - Insert copy into Context2

Answer (score 0):

I know this response is a little late but... This is absolutely possible. Since you are pointing towards two separate databases I don't see any issues at all.